# LWJGL is only rendering one object

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl

As the title suggests, I am trying to render two three-dimensional objects simultaneously using LWJGL, however, only the second one is rendering. I did a bit of searching around and added `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()` before and after each render. In addition, I am trying to render each object dynamically, rather than statically, with the use of an ArrayList.
Actual rendering code, called once every frame:

```
//clear screen and depth buffer
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
//this is done dynamically
for (int i = 0; i < MainProgram.renderer.parts.size(); i++) {
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    BasePart p = MainProgram.renderer.parts.get(i);
    glTranslatef(p.Position.X+MainProgram.CurrentCamera.CoordinateFrame.X, p.Position.Y-MainProgram.CurrentCamera.CoordinateFrame.Y, -MainProgram.zoom+p.Position.Z-MainProgram.CurrentCamera.CoordinateFrame.Z);
    if (MainProgram.renderer.rbd == true) {
        p.Rotation.Y += MainProgram.renderer.ydif;
        p.Rotation.X += MainProgram.renderer.xdif;
    }
    glRotatef(p.Rotation.X, 0f, 1f, 0f);
    glRotatef(-p.Rotation.Y, 1f, 0f, 0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(p.BrickColor.r, p.BrickColor.g, p.BrickColor.b); //green
        glVertex3f(p.Size.X, p.Size.Y, -p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(-p.Size.X, p.Size.Y, -p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(-p.Size.X, p.Size.Y, p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(p.Size.X, p.Size.Y, p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(p.Size.X, -p.Size.Y, p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(-p.Size.X, -p.Size.Y, p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(-p.Size.X, -p.Size.Y, -p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(p.Size.X, -p.Size.Y, -p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(p.Size.X, p.Size.Y, p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(-p.Size.X, p.Size.Y, p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(-p.Size.X, -p.Size.Y, p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(p.Size.X, -p.Size.Y, p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(p.Size.X,-p.Size.Y,-p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(-p.Size.X,-p.Size.Y,-p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(-p.Size.X, p.Size.Y,-p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(p.Size.X, p.Size.Y,-p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(-p.Size.X, p.Size.Y, p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(-p.Size.X, p.Size.Y, -p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(-p.Size.X, -p.Size.Y, -p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(-p.Size.X, -p.Size.Y, p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(p.Size.X, p.Size.Y, -p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(p.Size.X, p.Size.Y, p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(p.Size.X, -p.Size.Y, p.Size.Z);
        glVertex3f(p.Size.X, -p.Size.Y, -p.Size.Z);
    glEnd();
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
}
```

Size, Position, Rotation, and CoordinateFrame are all classes with X, Y, and Z values. `MainProgram.renderer.parts` is an ArrayList that holds the objects to be rendered. I suspect that the problem lies somewhere in the actual rendering (`glBegin()` to `glEnd()`), as I don't really see how the rotation could be a problem. Both objects render separately just fine, they just don't both render at the same time. They are two different sizes, and one is larger than the other. No matter the order they are in, however, only the second one renders.

Comment: Does it work if you try to render two objects manually (without a loop)?

Comment: No, it still only renders the last object to be rendered.

Comment: But they are on different positions/have  different sizes?

Comment: They do have visibly different positions, sizes, and colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem: I was clearing the buffers every time I wanted to draw something. I've moved the clear now, and it works.